# jquery drop down search box by clicking an icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

its an i tag
(the image is) 
which uses css to display the icons
through a cdn hosted stylesheet and how would I incorporate that.

So lets say there is a magnifying glass icon on the web page, we the user clicks on the icon , a div dropdown search box appears. that is what i am asking help for.
not sure how to do it but I know I am close. 
The icon is the

```
<section class="search">
    <div id="searchbar"><i class="search-bar"></i></div>
    <div class="search-dropdown hidden">   
        <div class="searchbox">
        <input placeholder="search..." type="text"/>
    </div>
</div>
</section>
```

//// javascript////

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#searchbar').click(function(){
        $(this).siblings('.search-dropdown').toggleClass('hidden');
    });
});
```

Comment: need more info about cdn you use. Also here must be some javascript for creating dropdown.

Comment: Please elaborate your question

Comment: There's an error in the markup (an extra `<div>`). Although I'm not sure I understand your question/problem, the code you posted should do what you expect it to do.

Comment: Your code seems correct, what problem are you experiencing?

Comment: @AdrianForsius I can't pull it up in my text editor and the <i class = "search-bar"></i> doesnt seem to be pulling up either when I called it. I should give it a more appropriate name <i class ="icon" ></i>

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what your goal is, but your code seems to work.

Have you checked so your div wraps around the image so when you click it you click inside the div (try to do as I in the fiddle, a border around the div so you can see).

else it should work just fine.

What is the css for the .hidden class?

```
<style>
.hidden
{
background-color: yellow;
}

#searchbar
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 16px;
    width: 50px;
}
</style>

<section class="search">
    <div id="searchbar"><i class="search-bar">CLICK</i></div>
    <div class="search-dropdown hidden">   
        <div class="searchbox">
        <input placeholder="search..." type="text"/>
    </div>
</div>
</section>
```

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#searchbar').click(function(){
        $(this).siblings('.search-dropdown').toggleClass('hidden');
    });
});
```

Check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fv6be245/1/) out!

Comment: Pleace add something like style="background-color: yellow;" to your searchbar div like this: <div id="searchbar" style="background-color: yellow;"> And check if your div is actually wraping around the other objects. If you cant se the yellow div or you can just se a tiny line of yellow, it means you have to make the div bigger. Cuz your code says that you have to press inside the div to actually trigger the javascript.